# Replace a Number with a Random Number

Tags: c#, arrays, encryption, replace, binary

I want to make my own little encryption (it not must be secure).
I thought it would be a good idea, if the entered password would be converted to binary and then I want to change all the 1 to (2 | 3 | 9 | 7) so if we had

> 1101 = 2907 | 9703 ... and so on

So if we would enter 9703 we could decrypt it to 1101 again.

But I can’t find a Method to Replace these. 
The Replace() Method would only do this:

> 1101 -> 2202 | 1101 -> 9909

And yes, i know that is not a good Method to encrypt something but I just want to code a very simple encryption on my own.

```
int[] replace_Ones = { 2, 3, 9, 7 };

int ServerEncryption = 1101010000111001;

ServerEncryption.Replace(1, 2);
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you're requirements are for replacing characters. I don't understand what is meant by *"change all the 1 to (2 | 3 | 9 | 7)"*. Can you please try to clarify?

Comment: `int[] replace_Ones = { 2, 3, 9, 7, 0 };` - you may want to think about that last item again.

Comment: Please add `Replace`'s implementation, so we can give you some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from this:

```
int[] replace_Ones = { 2, 3, 9, 7 }; // I removed the 0 ;)

long ServerEncryption = 1101010000111001;
```

You can make a method that does the following:

```
long FunnyEncrypt( long pseudobinary )
{
    long result = 0;
    long scope = 1;
    while( pseudobinary > 0 )
    {
        //        place   2 or 3 or 7 or 9         0 or 1
        result += scope * GetRandomReplacement() * ( pseudobinary % 10 );
        scope *= 10;
        pseudobinary = pseudobinary / 10; // decimal right shift 110 / 10 -> 11
    }
    return result;
}
```

Disclaimer: untested! Corrections welcome.

`GetRandomReplacement` is left for practice :D - but it basically is "pick a random int out of [0..3] and use it as index into the array of [2,3,7,9]".

Example:

```
example input: 1101

| iteration | input | result | scope | -> | input | result | scope | GetRandomRepl | 
| 1         | 1101  |   0    | 1     | -> |   110 |      7 |    10 |         7     |
| 2         |  110  |   7    | 10    | -> |    11 |      7 |   100 |         -     |
| 3         |   11  |   7    | 100   | -> |     1 |    307 |  1000 |         3     | 
| 4         |    1  | 307    | 1000  | -> |     0 |   2307 | 10000 |         2     |

=> Result = 2307
```

EDIT: changed to `long` after testing, did not see the number is too big for int: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5X4lZu

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is to replace '1' value of a binary string to a random value in { 2, 3, 9, 7 } you could do like this:

```
char[] replace_Ones = { '2', '3', '9', '7' };
        StringBuilder ServerEncryption =new StringBuilder("1101010000111001");
        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i=0 ; i < ServerEncryption.Length ; i++)
        {

            if (ServerEncryption[i] != '0')
                ServerEncryption[i] = replace_Ones[r.Next(replace_Ones.Length)];
        }
        Console.WriteLine(ServerEncryption);
```

[dotnetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jjo7U5)